# C# Task.Factory.NewTask and WCF. Why I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an application in WCF that runs in all machines on my customer. But just one works like a server in the net.

In this model, every time the WCF "client" is called, he call your WCF "server" to obtain your response.

So, I have this configuration on my Interface:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
MyObjectReturn CheckUpdate(string foo1, string foo2, string foo3);
```

In my code, this:

```
MyObjectReturn myObjReturn = new MyObjectReturn();
if (this.Master)
{
   myObjReturn.Code = 15000;
   myObjReturn.Message = "New Update found";
   return myObjReturn;
}
else
{
   var myTask = Task<MyObjectReturn >.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      ServerContractClient server = new ServerContractClient(master.Url);
      return server.CheckUpdate(foo1, foo2, foo3);
   } 
   return myTask.Result;
}
```

When the WCF "client" calls his "server", the return is always null! If I do not use the "Task . Factory.StartNew", I get a Bad Request error

Any tip?

Comment: There's really no point to starting a new task just to get it's result right away.  You're performing a blocking wait on it right away, so you might as well just do the work synchronously.  If you don't want to do the work synchronously then you need to not do a blocking wait on the task.

Answer (score 4):

Uh, first, "server" and "client" are the [preferred nomenclatures](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYOzUHnPJvU&ei=TVYCUvOLCLOgyQGX6IDoAg&usg=AFQjCNHLiUTuziHsnLoycgbYybwpSzbLDA&sig2=D2x79-oiJFVZFP5sKOW9KA&bvm=bv.50310824,d.aWc).

Second, Servy has a point that if you want the data back immediately, there's no real point in starting a thread. That said, threads are fun! Who doesn't want to thread? To do it properly you'll have to revise your application a bit, but for now you'll at least have to design the WCF method to be asynchronous, and the client making the call needs to know it's asynchronous; otherwise the result is null, as you experienced. Best starting point is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx).

Comment: You can't design a WCF operation to be asynchronous unless the binding you're using is truly one-way (like netMsmqBinding). You can consume any synchronous WCF operation asynchronously only on the client end.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've pretty much used HTTP binding exclusively in my work with WCF, and did a test project a few months ago that was asynchronous with that (and that included a client consuming those methods). I linked that article because that's what I used to do that project and it doesn't even mention binding. Now .NET might be covering up my failure as a developer, but at the very least you can make an asynchronous WCF method with HTTP...

Comment: OK we're at cross purposes here - when I said you can't make an asynchronous operation I meant that there's nothing in the operation contracts which state that the service will do anything asynchronously when the operation is called. So what I meant was regardless of whether the call handling code is multithreaded, the client can call the service operations either synchronously or asynchronously depending on their need.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's true; the server could just decide to go take a nap. I'm just assuming, based on experience, that if he wants to thread his response, it's going to have to come back asynchronously; I'd run into a similar problem in the past where sparking a thread in the response to return a result caused the client to see the response as null. Anyway, my initial response sounded more angry than actually intended; I appreciate the input, even if we're almost completely off-topic at this point :D

Comment: Glad we sorted that one out ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm ashamed to say it, but the problem was not what I thought. I noticed that when I called the WCF Server via browser, my return was not null. It was then that I realized that my Binding was the real problem. I noticed that there were two errors:

1) My Bindding is created via code. As noted in my interface, I declared my WebMessageBodyStyle as WrappedRequest. But when creating the Binding Client, I was using Wrapped;

2) The namespace of my ServiceBehavior and DataContract were different, which also caused confusion in WCF.

**This link helped me clarify this last point:**

[WCF Web Service Call to Another WCF Web Service returns no data](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311761/WCF-Web-Service-Call-to-Another-WCF-Web-Service-re)

Anyway, thank you all who gave me very valuable tips on this problem.